# Reading first four bytes from ByteBuffer, then writing them back?

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer

I have a ByteBuffer object called `msg` with the intended message length in the first four bytes, which I read as follows:

```
    int msgLen = msg.getInt();
    LOG.debug("Message size: " + msgLen);
```

If the `msgLen` is less than some threshold value, I have a partial message and need to cache.  In this case, I'd like to put those first four bytes back into the beginning of the message; that is, put the message back together to be identical to pre-reading.  For example:

```
if (msgLen < threshold) {
    msg.rewind();
    msg.put(msgLen);
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be the correct way to do this.  I've tried many combinations of flip, put, and rewind, but must be misunderstanding.

How would I put the bytes back into the write buffer in their original order?

Comment: Unclear why should you "put" these bytes "back"? If you do `rewind` you are already at the begging of `msg`,  those obtained bytes aren't erased from buffer.

Comment: If my stream couldn't get rewound, it would raise an error, right?  My debugger shows that the rewinder operation does reset the position.  Andremoniy, thanks I thought bytes were consumed on read.  Still not getting intended behavior, but maybe that's on my end.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. ByteBuffers are not streams

Comment: Back to the problem at hand; if you have a "partial read" from a message, how can you associate any further input to a previous partial read? Do you have some sort of id? If you don't, then how do you handle multiple partial reads?

Comment: Thanks fge, you mean partial reads from multiple input sources?  IE 2 messages sent in partial chunks simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Answer was posted by Andremoniy in comments section.  Read operations do not consume bytes in the buffer, so `msg.rewind()` was adequate.  This didn't work in my case because of some other logic in the program, and I incorrectly associated that with a problem at the buffer level.